How to hide/exclude certain properties of schema for response in yaml file?
For example I have schema, described below. In the first case I want to return all fields, in the second case I want to return all except "healty" and "color". For some reason I do not need them  for the second request. How do I do that?
paths:
  /pet:
    get:
      tags:
        - pet
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'          
  /pet/findByConition:
    get:
        tags:
          - pet
        responses:
          '200':
            description: ''
            content:
              application/json:
                schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'  
components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
        name: 
          type: string
        wight: 
          type: integer
        height: 
          type: integer
        weight: 
          type: integer          
        color: 
          type: string
        healty: 
          type: string


You need two schemas:

the base schema with just the common properties,
another schema that uses allOf to extend the base schema with additional properties.

components:
  schemas:
    BasePet:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
        name: 
          type: string
        wight: 
          type: integer
        height: 
          type: integer
        weight: 
          type: integer          

    Pet:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/BasePet'
        - properties:
            color: 
              type: string
            healty: 
              type: string

Then update your operations so that each references its relevant schema:
paths:
  /pet:
    get:
          ...
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/BasePet'   # <-----
        
  /pet/findByConition:
    get:
            ...
            content:
              application/json:
                schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'     # <-----

